# Ruby regex match starting at specific position

Tags: ruby, regex

In Python I can do this:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('a')

regex.match('xay',1)  # match because string starts with 'a' at 1
regex.match('xhay',1) # no match because character at 1 is 'h'
```

However in Ruby, the `match` method seems to match everything past the positional argument. For instance, `/a/.match('xhay',1)` will return a match, even though the match actually starts at 2. However, I want to only consider matches that start at a specific position.

How do I get a similar mechanism in Ruby? I would like to match patterns that start at a specific position in the string as I can in Python.

Comment: Why not `str[1] == 'a'` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I admit the example I gave was rather elementary, but in my program, I have a collection of regexes, and I tokenize a string, with some logic determining which regex I use for the next token based on which previous regexes match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about below using [`StringScanner`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html#method-i-scan) ?

```
require 'strscan'

scanner =  StringScanner.new 'xay'
scanner.pos = 1
!!scanner.scan(/a/) # => true

scanner =  StringScanner.new 'xnnay'
scanner.pos = 1
!!scanner.scan(/a/) # => false
```

Comment: Be warned your solution won't work with multi-byte chars like utf-8 encoded: `scanner = StringScanner.new 'áay'; scanner.pos=1; scanner.scan(/a/)  # => nil`

Comment: Much better solution is to rely on regexp patterns like `/^.(a)/`.

Comment: @DavidUnric Well. Then I need to inform Ruby core. It should be implemented there. If I include this - http://rubydoc.info/gems/unicode_utils/1.4.0/file/README.rdoc, also it didn't work.

Comment: @ArupRakshit StringScanner class already differentiates between byte and char position. There is a getter [StringScanner#charpos](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/strscan/rdoc/StringScanner.html#method-i-charpos), complementary setter is missing. However the example can be rewritten like `StringScanner.new 'áay'; scanner.scan_until(/a/) ? scanner.charpos-1 == 1 : false  # true` .

Comment: @DavidUnric Like it .. +1

Comment: @DavidUnric Don't you think, we should open a ticket..regarding the *regex*, you shown in the comment. It should work. Currently it is a miss of implementation.

Answer (score 4):

```
/^.{1}a/
```

for matching `a` at location `x+1` in the string

```
/^.{x}a/
```

--> [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/WTucYHMUOC)

Comment: While this does technically answer my question, in my program I don't have access to the actual regex literal (I am passed the regex as a function argument). I suppose I could convert to the regex to a string and mess around, but perhaps there is a cleaner method?

Comment: You can interpolate into the regex and shouldn't look too akward.

Answer (score 1):

[`Regexp#match`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html#method-i-match) has an optional second parameter `pos`, but it works like Python's `search` method. You could however check if the returned [`MatchData`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/MatchData.html) begins at the specified position:

```
re = /a/

match_data = re.match('xay', 1)
match_data.begin(0) == 1
#=> true

match_data = re.match('xhay', 1)
match_data.begin(0) == 1
#=> false

match_data = re.match('áay', 1)
match_data.begin(0) == 1
#=> true

match_data = re.match('aay', 1)
match_data.begin(0) == 1
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending a little bit on what @sunbabaphu answered:

```
def matching_at_pos(x=0, regex)
  /\A.{#{x-1}}#{regex}/ 
end # note the position is 1 indexed

'xxa' =~ matching_at_pos(2, /a/)
=> nil
'xxa' =~ matching_at_pos(3, /a/)
=> 0
'xxa' =~ matching_at_pos(4, /a/)
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is `\G`.

`\G` matches the starting point of the regex match, when calling the two-argument version of `String#match` that takes a starting position.

```
'xay'.match(/\Ga/, 1) # match because /a/ starts at 1
'xhay'match(/\Ga/, 1) # no match because character at 1 is 'h'
```